# How to use Reduce() function in R parallel computing?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, reduce

I want to run a `Reduce` code to `out1` a list of 66000 list elements:

```
trialStep1_done <- Reduce(rbind, out1)
```

However, it takes too long to run. I wonder whether I can run this code with help of a parallel computing package.

I know there is `mclapply`, `mcMap`, but I don't see any function like `mcReduce` in parallel computing package.

Is there a function like `mcReduce` available for doing `Reduce` with parallel in R to complete the task I wanted to do?

Thanks a lot @BrodieG and @zheYuan Li, your answers are very helpful. I think the following code example can represent my question with more precision:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=letters, b=LETTERS, c=1:26 %>% as.character())
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(a=letters %>% sample(), b=LETTERS %>% sample(), c=1:26 %>% sample() %>% as.character())
set.seed(1234)
df3 <- data.frame(a=letters %>% sample(), b=LETTERS %>% sample(), c=1:26 %>% sample() %>% as.character())
out1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# I don't know how to rbind() the list elements only using matrix()
# I have to use lapply() and Reduce() or do.call()
out2 <- lapply(out1, function(x) matrix(unlist(x), ncol = length(x), byrow = F))

Reduce(rbind, out2)
do.call(rbind, out2)
# One thing is sure is that `do.call()` is super faster than `Reduce()`, @BordieG's answer helps me understood why.
```

So, at this point, to my 200000 rows dataset, `do.call()` solves the problem very well.

Finally, I wonder whether this is an even faster way? or the way @ZheYuanLi demostrated with just `matrix()` could be possible here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not `rbind`, the problem is `Reduce`.  Unfortunately, function calls in R are expensive, and particularly so when you keep creating new objects.  In this case, you call `rbind` 65999 times, and each time you do you create a new R object with one row added.  Instead, you can just call `rbind` once with 66000 arguments, which will be much faster since internally `rbind` will do the binding in C without having to call R functions 66000 times and allocating the memory just once.  Here we compare your `Reduce` use with Zheyuan's matrix/unlist and finally with `rbind` called once with `do.call` (`do.call` allows you to call a function with all arguments specified as a list):

```
out1 <- replicate(1000, 1:20, simplify=FALSE)  # use 1000 elements for illustrative purposes

library(microbenchmark)    
microbenchmark(times=10,
  a <- do.call(rbind, out1),
  b <- matrix(unlist(out1), ncol=20, byrow=TRUE),
  c <- Reduce(rbind, out1)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                                                expr        min         lq
#                           a <- do.call(rbind, out1)    469.873    479.815
#  b <- matrix(unlist(out1), ncol = 20, byrow = TRUE)    257.263    260.479
#                            c <- Reduce(rbind, out1) 110764.898 113976.376
all.equal(a, b, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(b, c, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Zheyuan is the fastest, but for all intents and purposes the `do.call(rbind())` method is pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your beautiful explanation of why `do.call` is so much faster than `Reduce`. It does speed up greatly!

Answer (score 5):

1. It is slow, because you **repeatedly** call `rbind`. Every time it is called, new memory allocation has to be done as the object's dimension is increasing.
2. Your work is memory-bound, and you are not going to benefit from parallelism. On a multi-core machine, parallel processing is only useful for CPU-bound tasks.

If I did not get you wrong, you should probably use this:

```
trialStep1_done <- matrix(unlist(out1), nrow = length(out1), byrow = TRUE)
```

Example:

```
out1 <- list(1:4, 11:14, 21:24, 31:34)

#> str(out1)
#List of 4
# $ : int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
# $ : int [1:4] 11 12 13 14
# $ : int [1:4] 21 22 23 24
# $ : int [1:4] 31 32 33 34

trialStep1_done <- matrix(unlist(out1), nrow = length(out1), byrow = TRUE)

#> trialStep1_done
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]   11   12   13   14
#[3,]   21   22   23   24
#[4,]   31   32   33   34
```

---

Thanks for @BrodieG's excellent explanation and benchmarking result!

I tried the benchmarking on my laptop as well, using exactly the same code as @BrodieG's, and this is what I get:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                               expr      min       lq      mean
                          a <- do.call(rbind, out1)   653.60   670.36   900.120
 b <- matrix(unlist(out1), ncol = 20, byrow = TRUE)   170.16   177.60   224.036
                           c <- Reduce(rbind, out1) 65589.48 67519.32 72317.812
   median       uq       max neval
   745.54   832.36   2352.28    10
   183.98   286.84    385.96    10
 68897.36 69372.88 108135.96    10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, particularly the comment on **parallel** part. My question related to your comment is:
Could `do.call(rbind, out2)` be benefited from parallelism, if not `Reduce(rbind, out2)`?

Comment: @Kenny, as Zheyuan points out, they underlying constraint is the allocation and copying of memory.  Parallelizing will probably make all this slower because it will require even more copies: first, split the data along the processors, then recombine it back in the master thread.

Comment: @BrodieG, Thanks. Please allow me to rephrase what I gathered from the answers from you and Zheyuan. 
1. parallelism is useful in cases when I have a lot of calculations or math to do (require a lot of CPU) rather than a lot to split, copy and rbind of data objects like data.frame, or list (require a lot of memory). 
2. in my case, split big data.frame to lists of data.frame, and convert list of data.frame to list of matrix, rbind list of matrix to a single matrix, all these are about memory work, not computational work. 
3. Therefore, `rbind` won't have anything to do with parallel

Comment: @Kenny, yes, pretty much.  If you had a long processor intensive somewhere in there, then it may make sense to parallelize that.