# how to count binary patterns

Tags: r, data.table

This problem has many applications. I want to identify and count unique binary patterns in many variables. I found something close to what I was looking for, but I can't finish the code.

[countpattern {e1071}](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/e1071/html/countpattern.html)

same data as in the link:

```
library(data.table)
xx <- rbind(c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,1),c(0,1,1),c(0,1,1))
xx <- as.data.table(xx)

library(e1071)
countpattern(xx[,1:3])
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 
  0   0   0   2   2   1   0   0 

(cols <- names(which(countpattern(xx[,1:3])>0)))
for(i in cols) { xx[,i] <- as.character("") }  # ... and that's it :(

xx
   V1 V2 V3 011 100 101
1:  1  0  0            
2:  1  0  0            
3:  1  0  1            
4:  0  1  1            
5:  0  1  1
```

I have the data.table and the columns, and I want to populate them with TRUE/FALSE or 1/0 when the pattern in each row matches the available column names. End result should look like this:

```
xx
   V1 V2 V3 011 100 101
1:  1  0  0   0   1   0          
2:  1  0  0   0   1   0             
3:  1  0  1   0   0   1            
4:  0  1  1   1   0   0            
5:  0  1  1   1   0   0
```

I've tried several versions of the fast `for (i in seq_along) {set(DT, i, 1L, i)}`, but my goals are greater than my skills.

Thanks,
Aldo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do this

```
library(data.table)
#Paste all the binary columns together rowwise
vals <- do.call(paste0, xx)
#Get only unique values
unique_vals <- unique(vals)
#Initialise the columns to 0
xx[, (unique_vals) := 0]

#Create a matrix with row and column index and replace those position with 1
xx[cbind(seq_len(nrow(xx)), match(vals, unique_vals) + 3)] <- 1
#Replace 3 with number in original columns
xx
#   V1 V2 V3 100 101 011
#1:  1  0  0   1   0   0
#2:  1  0  0   1   0   0
#3:  1  0  1   0   1   0
#4:  0  1  1   0   0   1
#5:  0  1  1   0   0   1
```

---

`countpattern` from `e1071` returns all possible patterns, we can use that function with `matching = TRUE` to get the index of match and then use that information to turn columns to 1.

```
library(e1071)

pat <- countpattern(xx, matching=TRUE)
xx[, (names(pat$pat)) := 0]
xx[cbind(seq_len(nrow(xx)), pat$matching + 3)] <- 1

xx
#   V1 V2 V3 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
#1:  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
#2:  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
#3:  1  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
#4:  0  1  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
#5:  0  1  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: holy! that was fast. I wasn't expecting it. And it works!

Comment: @504aldo Thanks! Also updated the answer using `countpattern` function.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, they work. I like the first one better because i don't want to depend on `e1071`. If you don't mind, would you help me understant 2 lines: 1) what `do.call` does? - I can see the end result, but all sorts of combinations of `paste0(xx, collapse = "")` or `paste... anything` will not produce the same results as `do.call`. I'm going trough `?do.call` but still. And 2) that last line, i know you are binding columns to `xx` but i still don't understand _why_ it works. Also, can i replace the `+3` with `+length(unique_vals)` instead?

Comment: @504aldo 1) If you check the output of `do.call` it pastes all the values of the column rowwise. So `do.call(paste0, xx)` is same as `apply(xx, 1, paste0, collapse = "")` 2) We have already bind the columns in earlier line (`(unique_vals) := 0`). The `match` is used to get the column number where we need to assign 1. and no you cannot replace `+3` with `length(unique_vals)` because `length(unique_vals)` is the number of  new columns to add whereas `+3` is the number of original columns in the dataframe before adding new columns which co-incidentally happen to be the same in this case.

Comment: thanks for helping me understand. `apply(xx, 1, paste0, collapse = "")` - OMG I feel so embarrassed i didn't think of this. After some trial and error I came with an additional alternative: `Reduce(paste0, xx)`, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636463/how-to-use-reduce-function-in-r-parallel-computing), `Reduce` is slower than `do.call`